# Implementing python group by based on monthly sales

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following table:

```
  Date      sales     product
(yyyy-mm)
2020-4.    78       SampleA
2020-5.    76       SampleB
2020-3.    72.      SampleA
2020-8.    99.      SampleC
2020-4.    32.      SampleA
```

I want a table based on group by month based on new attribute of each product using python

```
  Date(group by month).    SampleA. SampleB. SampleC
   2020-3                    72.      0.       0.
   2020-4                    110      0.       0
   2020-5                     0.      76       0
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you have fixed number of Product/Sample?

Comment: There are 9-10 products.

Comment: I want to implement in python. No

Comment: use pandas.melt

Comment: Help me with code. Noob in python

Answer (score 0):

Try `.pivot_table()` with `"sum"` as aggregation function:

```py
x = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index="Date",
        columns="product",
        values="sales",
        aggfunc="sum",
        fill_value=0,
    )
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
     Date  SampleA  SampleB  SampleC
0  2020-3       72        0        0
1  2020-4      110        0        0
2  2020-5        0       76        0
3  2020-8        0        0       99
```

Comment: @user8238629 make sure you have `"sales"` column in your dataframe (without spaces etc.)

Comment: is there code to check that. Some values are in decimal

Comment: @user8238629 You can do `print(df.columns)`

Comment: datatype is object

Comment: @user8238629 I mean column name. Make sure you have column named `"sales"` in your dataframe to not get `KeyError`

Comment: I think its not part of the dataframe and some values are ####. How to deal with that?

Comment: it says DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sales'

Comment: @user8238629 Without seeing your real dataframe is hard to tell.

Comment: Can you give common solution to this?

Comment: @user8238629 make sure the `values=` parameter in `.pivot_table` contains column that exists in your dataframe

Comment: 86         for i in values:
     87             if i not in data:
---> 88                 raise KeyError(i)
     89 
     90         to_filter = []
key error

Comment: There is some problem in sales column. It's there but not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use df(pd.grouper(key=‘Date’,freq=“M”))[“sales”].sum()